# Размещение Symfony3 проекта на VPS

Tags: vps, symfony3

Привет всем! Помогите разместить проект на VPS, система CentOS. Папку web сервер видит, для проверки создал в web index.php - Работает. При вызову app.php не грузит ничего. Может дело в правах?

Что можно проверить и в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Что выдаёт `php bin/symfony_requirements`? Есть ли проблемы?
`SYMFONY_ENV=prod php bin/console` отрабатывает?

Comment: console вообще не отрабатывает. Только пытался сгенерить базу, никакой реакции. На php bin/symfony_requirements тоже.

Comment: Почему может не работать консоль?

Comment: Поставьте права 777, проверьте, работает ли. Поймете, в правах ли дело. Только назад потом верните :) Так же смотрите error.log вашего веб-сервера (apache/nginx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [ссылка](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) на документация по настройки веб сервера для Symfony.

Comment: php не отрабатывает теперь( Сделал конфиг по Вашей ссылке, второй по очереди который

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/project/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
    # which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
    <Directory /var/www/project/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```